# Using IApplicationAssociationRegistration from a service

Tags: winapi, com

I'm having a problem using IApplicationAssociationRegistration to check the default email client. In the user context everything is fine, but from a service running in the system context the wrong default client is being returned as it seems to be picking up values from the system user rather than the current logged in user.

Here are the steps I take:

1) Call CoInitialize and CoInitializeSecurity for impersonation.

2) Call DuplicateTokenEx to get a security token for SecurityImpersonation of the logged in user.

3) Call ImpersonateLoggedOnUser with the token.

4) Call CoCreateInstance to create an instance of IApplicationAssociationRegistration. I get S_OK returned and an instance pointer.

5) Call CoSetProxyBlanket for both the instance pointer I got from step (4) and the IUnknown pointer. Again I get S_OK returned.

6) Call the method IApplicationAssociationRegistration::QueryAppIsDefault for Outlook using the instance pointer I got from step (4). Again I get S_OK returned, but in the system context I get TRUE returned, and in the user context I correctly get FALSE returned. If I manually modify the UrlAssociations/mailto/UserChoice/ProgId value for HKEY_USERS/.DEFAULT in regedit and call again, it picks up the new value.

7) Similarly if I call SetAppAsDefault, it seems to set the associations in the system context, rather than the user context as I want.

If I put steps 4 to 7 into a console application and run this from the service using CreateProcessAsUser, then it works fine. But I would rather avoid having to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So I guess the answer is you're stuck, and doing it the way you did it is the right way to go.  Nowadays in Windows 8 it's even more locked down, with the hash-feature so you can't manually generate associations via registry-modification directly.